# Error when trying to bold text immediately after opening parenthesis

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, markdown

I [posted an answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960062/can-not-resolve-style-from-master-pages-pageload/1960070#1960070) where the formatting wasn't able to pick up the asterisks used for bold (`**`).

Note the following attempt to use bold right after an opening parenthesis (and not working here, since the editors are the same):

> (**not** the master page)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was experimenting with stricter interpretations of bold and italic.

We have a lot of problems with StackExchange sites (particularly Math Overflow, and all their wacky math notation schemes) where bold and italic are interfering.

In the meantime, we reverted to something similar to the Markdown standard..

http://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/source/detail?r=16

So the `***bold and italic***` should now work: ***bold and italic***

Answer (score 2):

Due to the way Markdown works, particularly on SO, sometimes you have to resort to HTML.

You can fix this by typing:

```
(<b>not</b> the but the one that uses it)
```

Which will render as:

> (**not** the but the one that uses
>   it)

I copied and pasted directly from your SO answer. I think there's a word missing (my hunch is "master"), but I'm not 100% sure. If you correct your SO answer, please let me know via a comment and I'll correct this one to match.

Comment: @Mark 8-36 I appreciate the *workaround*.  The post was more an issue with the Markdown parser on the server side and to inform SO.  FWIW, what you propose isn't a fix, the fix is on the server side according to the Markdown documentation on how it is interpreted.  Also, there is nothing *missing* per se, the example here is just that, an example of the condition.  Thanks though.